# Day of week from seconds since epoch

Tags: c, time

I'm trying to calculate the day of week from a seconds since epoch timestamp. From `time.h` I can use `gmtime()`, but this increases the program with 1.3kB, probably because `gmtime()` also calculates the date.

So, I'm wondering what would be wrong about using something like:

```
(timestamp / (24*3600)) % 7
```

The only thing I could think of is leap seconds, such that something like 00:00:02 could be classified as the wrong day.

**edit**
This is for embedded programming, 1.3kB is a substantial part of the 64kB program/firmware. Furthermore, I'm not expecting to do anything with timezones or dates after this.

Comment: Your code doesn't support timezones.

Comment: For a trivial program, 1.3kB more or less won't really matter since, well, it's a trivial one-off example. For a non-trivial program, 1.3kB more or less won't really matter either because there will be many other, similarily large (or even larger) chunks linked in anyway. I think you should just go for `gmtime()`. Avoiding standard functions for homegrown code just gives you avoidable problems.

Comment: After a little thought, leap seconds are not really a problem since UNIX time doesn't account for them. I edited my comment above to reflect that.

Comment: About "seconds since epoch", note that it is a common misconception that this is what you get from `time()`. In actual fact, the encoding of what `time()` returns (`time_t`) is "implementation defined". You can get "seconds since epoch" from `timespec_get()`, and what "epoch" that is, again, is implementation-defined. Be careful with assumptions that way. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I edited the question a bit to define the problem better.Never knew that unix time didn't include leap seconds.

Comment: @DevSolar Disagree that 1.3kB does not matter.  1.3kB represents 3% of my embedded processor's code space.  Certainly a variation of `(timestamp / (24*3600)) % 7` is worth coding.

Comment: C does not specify that `gmtime()` work only with the UNIX definition of `time_t/struct tm` - although that is a common implementation.  Various time epochs, `time_t` types and additional fields of `struct tm` are possible in C.

Comment: @chux: The real point is the OP's edit that he doesn't intend to do anything *else* time-related. That is what makes some "homegrown" calculation truly feasible. That being said, I'm curious whether I can beat those 1.3kB when the time to implement `gmtime` comes around. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what would be wrong about using something like: (?)

```
(timestamp / (24*3600)) % 7
```

---

Not much wrong with the above except you have not specified the day of the week the epoch began (e.g. Thursday) nor the day of the week the week begins on (e.g. Monday).  See [8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates) for a deeper discusison on the first day of the week. Also watch out for computations like `24*3600` that with 16-bit `int/unsigned` lead to troubles.

Example: Let us say the epoch began on day-of-the-week number 3 (Monday:0.  Thursday:3).  This takes care of 2 issues at once: day of the week of the epoch and the first day of the week as only the positive difference needs to be coded.

```
#define EPOCH_DOW 3
#define SECS_PER_DAY 86400 
dow = ((timestamp / SECS_PER_DAY) + EPOCH_DOW) % 7;
```

If `timestamp` is a signed type, append the following to insure a result in the `[0...6]` range.

```
dow = (dow + 7) % 7;
// or 
if (dow < 0) dow += 7;
```

I doubt [leap seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second) are used in your application.  If they are, the task is *far* more complicated as code then needs to deal with not only with a more complex calculation, but how to receive updates of the next scheduled leap-seconds - they occur irregularly.

Answer (score 1):

You're off by 4, since January 1, 1970 was a Thursday, and you may compute an incorrect result for dates before the epoch depending on the behavior of `%` on negative operands. (The simplest fix is to check whether the result is negative, and if so add 7.) But other than this, your algorithm is correct; it's the same as used by [glibc internal function `__offtime`](https://fossies.org/dox/glibc-2.23/offtime_8c_source.html#l00029), which `gmtime` ultimately ends up calling. (You can't call it yourself, as it's an internal implementation detail).

There's no need to worry about leap seconds; Unix time ignores them.

I would recommend encapsulating the code in a (possibly inline) function, with the `gmtime` implementation as a comment of `#if 0` block, so that you can easily switch to it if you start needing to compute months/years as well.

Comment: "...depending on the behaviour of `%` on negative operands" -- C defines that behaviour strictly since (AFAIK) C99, and C++ does since C++11.